# R: How to generate a column with row values based on the nearest N row's values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, feature-engineering

I'm looking for a way to code a column based information in the previous N rows to a given row. The dataset is sorted.

In short, I want to create a column called `oneweeksince` that returns `TRUE` if the `victims` column is greater than 0 (or !NA) for seven rows after.

Put another way, if, for `row[i]`, `row[i]$victims > 0` within any row from `row[i - 7]` to `row[i]`, then `row[i]$oneweeksince` should be `TRUE`. The `oneweeksince` value should also be `TRUE` on rows in which `victims > 0` or `!is.na(victims)`

How can I automate the creation of this column/feature? It is also possible to use the date column to compute the date distance. I'm trying to avoid creating a loop because of the slow perf in R.

The dataset should look like this:

```
      date           oneweeksince victims
1    2009-01-01         FALSE      NA
2    2009-01-02         FALSE      NA
3    2009-01-03         FALSE      NA
4    2009-01-04         FALSE      NA
5    2009-01-05         FALSE      NA
6    2009-01-06         FALSE      NA
7    2009-01-07         FALSE      NA
8    2009-01-08          TRUE       1
9    2009-01-09          TRUE      NA
10   2009-01-10          TRUE      NA
11   2009-01-11          TRUE      NA
12   2009-01-12          TRUE      NA
13   2009-01-13          TRUE      NA
14   2009-01-14          TRUE      NA
15   2009-01-15          TRUE      NA
16   2009-01-16         FALSE      NA
17   2009-01-17         FALSE      NA
18   2009-01-18         FALSE      NA
19   2009-01-19         FALSE      NA
20   2009-01-20         FALSE      NA
```

The dataset is many years long so I need an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution from @G.Grothendieck

After some discussions, this is the most effective and efficient answer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(roll = rollapplyr(victims > 0, 8, any, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, partial = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(oneweeksince = roll > 0) %>%
  select(-roll)
```

#### Solution from my previous attempt

A solution using `rollapplyr` from the `zoo` package. `rollapplyr` can apply a function with a rolling window. In this case, we can specify the rolling window to be 8 and apply the `mean` function. Notice that `rollmean` function is not suitable in this case becuas we cannot specify `na.rm = TRUE` in the `rollmean` function. The last step is to simply evaluate if the `roll` column is larger than 1.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(roll = rollapplyr(victims, width = 8, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), fill = NA)) %>%
  mutate(oneweeksince = roll > 0) %>%
  select(-roll)
# dat2
#          date victims oneweeksince
# 1  2009-01-01      NA           NA
# 2  2009-01-02      NA           NA
# 3  2009-01-03      NA           NA
# 4  2009-01-04      NA           NA
# 5  2009-01-05      NA           NA
# 6  2009-01-06      NA           NA
# 7  2009-01-07      NA           NA
# 8  2009-01-08       1         TRUE
# 9  2009-01-09      NA         TRUE
# 10 2009-01-10      NA         TRUE
# 11 2009-01-11      NA         TRUE
# 12 2009-01-12      NA         TRUE
# 13 2009-01-13      NA         TRUE
# 14 2009-01-14      NA         TRUE
# 15 2009-01-15      NA         TRUE
# 16 2009-01-16      NA           NA
# 17 2009-01-17      NA           NA
# 18 2009-01-18      NA           NA
# 19 2009-01-19      NA           NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "      date           oneweeksince victims
1    '2009-01-01'         FALSE      NA
                  2    '2009-01-02'         FALSE      NA
                  3    '2009-01-03'         FALSE      NA
                  4    '2009-01-04'         FALSE      NA
                  5    '2009-01-05'         FALSE      NA
                  6    '2009-01-06'         FALSE      NA
                  7    '2009-01-07'         FALSE      NA
                  8    '2009-01-08'          TRUE       1
                  9    '2009-01-09'          TRUE      NA
                  10   '2009-01-10'          TRUE      NA
                  11   '2009-01-11'          TRUE      NA
                  12   '2009-01-12'          TRUE      NA
                  13   '2009-01-13'          TRUE      NA
                  14   '2009-01-14'          TRUE      NA
                  15   '2009-01-15'          TRUE      NA
                  16   '2009-01-16'         FALSE      NA
                  17   '2009-01-17'         FALSE      NA
                  18   '2009-01-18'         FALSE      NA
                  19   '2009-01-19'         FALSE      NA
                  20   '2009-01-20'         FALSE      NA",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$oneweeksince <- NULL
```

#### My second attempt

The OP pointed out that my solution will not work if there are entries in the first N rows where N is the window width. Here I provided a solution to address that. I am going to use the same example data frame except that I change the second row of `victims` to be `1`. The new solution needs functions from `purrr` and `tidyr`, so I load the `tidyverse` package for this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(roll = rollapplyr(victims, width = 8, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), fill = NA)) %>%
  # Split the data frame for the first width - 1 rows and others
  mutate(GroupID = ifelse(row_number() <= 7, 1L, 2L)) %>%
  split(.$GroupID) %>%
  # Check if the GroupID is 1. If yes, change the roll column to be the same as victims
  # After that, use fill to fill in NA
  map_if(function(x) unique(x$GroupID) == 1L, 
         ~.x %>% mutate(roll = victims) %>% fill(roll)) %>%
  # Combine data frames
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(oneweeksince = roll > 0) %>%
  select(-roll)
# dat2
# date victims GroupID oneweeksince
# 1  2009-01-01      NA       1           NA
# 2  2009-01-02       1       1         TRUE
# 3  2009-01-03      NA       1         TRUE
# 4  2009-01-04      NA       1         TRUE
# 5  2009-01-05      NA       1         TRUE
# 6  2009-01-06      NA       1         TRUE
# 7  2009-01-07      NA       1         TRUE
# 8  2009-01-08       1       2         TRUE
# 9  2009-01-09      NA       2         TRUE
# 10 2009-01-10      NA       2         TRUE
# 11 2009-01-11      NA       2         TRUE
# 12 2009-01-12      NA       2         TRUE
# 13 2009-01-13      NA       2         TRUE
# 14 2009-01-14      NA       2         TRUE
# 15 2009-01-15      NA       2         TRUE
# 16 2009-01-16      NA       2           NA
# 17 2009-01-17      NA       2           NA
# 18 2009-01-18      NA       2           NA
# 19 2009-01-19      NA       2           NA
# 20 2009-01-20      NA       2           NA
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "      date           oneweeksince victims
1    '2009-01-01'         FALSE      NA
                  2    '2009-01-02'         FALSE       1
                  3    '2009-01-03'         FALSE      NA
                  4    '2009-01-04'         FALSE      NA
                  5    '2009-01-05'         FALSE      NA
                  6    '2009-01-06'         FALSE      NA
                  7    '2009-01-07'         FALSE      NA
                  8    '2009-01-08'          TRUE       1
                  9    '2009-01-09'          TRUE      NA
                  10   '2009-01-10'          TRUE      NA
                  11   '2009-01-11'          TRUE      NA
                  12   '2009-01-12'          TRUE      NA
                  13   '2009-01-13'          TRUE      NA
                  14   '2009-01-14'          TRUE      NA
                  15   '2009-01-15'          TRUE      NA
                  16   '2009-01-16'         FALSE      NA
                  17   '2009-01-17'         FALSE      NA
                  18   '2009-01-18'         FALSE      NA
                  19   '2009-01-19'         FALSE      NA
                  20   '2009-01-20'         FALSE      NA",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat$oneweeksince <- NULL
```

Comment: Fails if adding this data at the beginning `2008-12-28 2`

Comment: This seems to fail if the date is within first N entries of the data.frame, where N is the window range.

Comment: @Robert I fail to understand why do you want to add `2008-12-28 2` at the beginning. Notice that in the example data frame, the `date` column is complete.  If you add `2008-12-28 2`, the `date` column is not complete as there are gaps. This becomes a different question. To address your question, we can convert the `date` column to `date` class and then use `complete` from the `tidyr` to expand the `date` column with completed date series. After that, we can use my solution. But since it is not a condition specified by the OP, I will not mention it in my answer.

Comment: I was thinking on a general approach where may be gaps in the data. Otherwise you are right.

Comment: Suggest using `rollapplyr(victims > 0, 8, any, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, partial = TRUE)`  .  The `partial` argument allows it to work with fewer than 8 elements at the beginning.

Comment: I'm not really worried about a 2008 date.. but I am worried about the first N date having a value fwiw.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Good to know the use of the `partial` argument. Thanks.

Comment: @www Do you mind updating your answer to use Partial? That seems much more sensible. Then I'll accept.

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample Update completed. Thanks.

Comment: @www Cool. It'd be good to rename "update" in the lower heading as that may seem like an update to the answer you posted at the top. Ill accept.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a rolling sum and test that it is greater than 0:

```
library(RcppRoll)
your_data$result = roll_sum(
  x = your_data$victims,
  n = 8, 
  na.rm = TRUE,
  fill = 0,
  align = "right"
) > 0
your_data
#          date oneweeksince victims result
# 1  2009-01-01        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 2  2009-01-02        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 3  2009-01-03        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 4  2009-01-04        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 5  2009-01-05        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 6  2009-01-06        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 7  2009-01-07        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 8  2009-01-08         TRUE       1   TRUE
# 9  2009-01-09         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 10 2009-01-10         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 11 2009-01-11         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 12 2009-01-12         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 13 2009-01-13         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 14 2009-01-14         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 15 2009-01-15         TRUE      NA   TRUE
# 16 2009-01-16        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 17 2009-01-17        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 18 2009-01-18        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 19 2009-01-19        FALSE      NA  FALSE
# 20 2009-01-20        FALSE      NA  FALSE
```

Using this data:

```
your_data = read.table(header = T, text = '      date           oneweeksince victims
1    2009-01-01         FALSE      NA
2    2009-01-02         FALSE      NA
3    2009-01-03         FALSE      NA
4    2009-01-04         FALSE      NA
5    2009-01-05         FALSE      NA
6    2009-01-06         FALSE      NA
7    2009-01-07         FALSE      NA
8    2009-01-08          TRUE       1
9    2009-01-09          TRUE      NA
10   2009-01-10          TRUE      NA
11   2009-01-11          TRUE      NA
12   2009-01-12          TRUE      NA
13   2009-01-13          TRUE      NA
14   2009-01-14          TRUE      NA
15   2009-01-15          TRUE      NA
16   2009-01-16         FALSE      NA
17   2009-01-17         FALSE      NA
18   2009-01-18         FALSE      NA
19   2009-01-19         FALSE      NA
20   2009-01-20         FALSE      NA')
```

Comment: Fails if adding this data at the beginning  `2008-12-28        2`

Comment: This seems to fail if the date is within first N entries of the data.frame, where N is the window range.

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample I'd suggest updating your sample data in the question to include this case. Seems to be a common point of failure.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Gregor's answer, but here are two alternatives.

### Base R

```r
x$y <- Sys.Date()[NA] # just a class-stable way
x$y[ !is.na(x$victims) ] <- x$date[ !is.na(x$victims) ]
x$since <- difftime(x$date, zoo::na.locf(x$y, na.rm = FALSE), units="days")
x$oneweeksince <- !is.na(x$since) & (0 <= x$since & x$since <= 7)
```

#### `dplyr`

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(
    y = zoo::na.locf(if_else(is.na(victims), date[NA], date), na.rm = FALSE),
    since = difftime(date, zoo::na.locf(if_else(is.na(victims), date[NA], date), na.rm = FALSE),
                     units = "days"),
    anotherweeksince = !is.na(since) & between(since, 0, 7)
  )
```

---

Data:

```r
x <- read.table(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE, text="
      date           oneweeksince victims
1    2009-01-01         FALSE      NA
2    2009-01-02         FALSE      NA
3    2009-01-03         FALSE      NA
4    2009-01-04         FALSE      NA
5    2009-01-05         FALSE      NA
6    2009-01-06         FALSE      NA
7    2009-01-07         FALSE      NA
8    2009-01-08          TRUE       1
9    2009-01-09          TRUE      NA
10   2009-01-10          TRUE      NA
11   2009-01-11          TRUE      NA
12   2009-01-12          TRUE      NA
13   2009-01-13          TRUE      NA
14   2009-01-14          TRUE      NA
15   2009-01-15          TRUE      NA
16   2009-01-16         FALSE      NA
17   2009-01-17         FALSE      NA
18   2009-01-18         FALSE      NA
19   2009-01-19         FALSE      NA
20   2009-01-20         FALSE      NA")
x$date <- as.Date(x$date)
```

Comment: Gregor's answer fails, per one commenter.

Comment: Right, works if adding this data at the beginning `2008-12-28 2 `

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the efficiency but one way to do this in base R using `sapply` would be for every row we go back 7 rows and check if it satisfies any of the condition and return a boolean output accordingly.

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(x) {
    temp = df$victims[x : pmax(1, x - 7)]
    any(temp > 0) & any(!is.na(temp))
})

#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
#    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Fails if adding this data at the beginning `2008-12-28 2`

Comment: @Robert How? OP has mentioned to check previous 7 rows and see if any `victims` has value greater than 0 and a non-NA value.

Comment: I was thinking on a general approach where may be gaps in the data. Otherwise you are right.